# Finding Top-n based on a column in Dataframe and lumping the rest into others

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to create another one that looks like this (for the purposes of plotting and reporting) :

[image]

I am able to get this done but it feels ultra clunky and inelegant. I would really appreciate it if someone could suggest a nice and pythonic way of going about it. My code is below. Thx

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

#Creating a sample dataset

alphabet = [chr(letter) for letter in range(97,108)]
scores = [random.randint(0,15) for item in range(11)]

res = dict(zip(alphabet, scores))

test_df = pd.DataFrame(list(res.items()),columns = ['Name','Score']) 


#Sorting the dataframe in descending order based on column of interest

test_df = test_df.sort_values(by=['Score'], ascending = False)


#Creating a column of rank, where low rank equals high number

test_df['ranking'] = np.arange(1,len(test_df)+1)


# converting the rank into top-5 and then everything else 6 

test_df['ranking'] = test_df['ranking'].apply(lambda x: x if x < 6 else 6)


# Grouping by rank columns, this lumps everything else together

test_df_group = test_df.groupby(['ranking']).agg({"Name" : ''.join, "Score" : sum})


#renaming the data as "others"

test_df_group['Name'] = test_df_group['Name'].apply(lambda x: x if len(x) < 2 else "Others")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) and [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

We can use `nlargest` to select the first `n` rows (ordered in descending order by `Score` column), then create a dictionary which contains the aggregation of rest of the rows, now append this dictionary to `topn` dataframe to get the desired result

```
topn = test_df.nlargest(5, 'Score')
remaining = {'Name': 'Others', 'Score': test_df['Score'].drop(topn.index).sum()}

topn.append(remaining, ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
     Name  Score
0       h     15
1       b     10
2       a      9
3       k      9
4       f      8
5  Others     32
```

Answer (score 1):

We could solve this by combining `nlargest` with `np.where` and `groupby` :

```
(df
 .assign(Name = lambda df: np.where(df.Score.isin(df.Score.nlargest()), 
                                    df.Name, 
                                    'others')
         )
.groupby('Name', as_index=False)
.sum()
)

     Name  Score
0       a     12
1       f     10
2       h     10
3       j     15
4       k     14
5  others     26
```